# How to process a table data in nant script?

Tags: mysql, automation, release, nant

I want to process my mysql table data inside nant script. My table contatins some image file path. using that path I need to do svn check out also. How can I do like that. Does it possible to fetch all mysql table rows using nant script and process it in a loop?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Use the  NAnt task from NAntContrib and output the results to a file.
   http://nantcontrib.sourceforge.net/release/0.91/help/tasks/sql.html
   Hint: Here is a sample MySql OleDb Connection String that can be used:

   Provider=MySQLProv;Data Source=mydb;User Id=myUsername;Password=myPassword;
2. Use a  task to loop over each line in the file:
   http://nant.sourceforge.net/release/0.91/help/tasks/foreach.html
3. Use the  task from NAntContrib to checkout the file from svn:
   http://nantcontrib.sourceforge.net/release/0.91/help/tasks/svn-checkout.html